# activation x activation 1D convolution in TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, convolution

I want to implement a 1D convolution in Tensorflow, but NOT between an activation layer and a common learned filter.  I want to perform a convolution on two different activations layers, such that the convolution is performed on each vector in the batch independently.  The standard TensorFlow conv1d assumes a common learn filter function. It takes activation input with dimensions  [batch, in_width, in_channels] and filter with dimensions  [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels].  Instead I want to do a set of 1D convolution between an activation with dimensions [batch_size, in_width] and a second activation with dimensions [batch_size,filter_width].  Numpy's convolve also doesn't do this because it operates on 1D arrays and doesn't appear to work across each of the batch_size subvectors.

The relevant section of TensorFlow code looks like this, to give a clearer idea of context:

```
# filter is created as an activation layer
filter = tf.nn.conv1d(h_conv5, W_fc, stride=1, padding = 'VALID') + b_fc
filter_res = tf.reshape(filter,[-1,flength])
# data is created from NN input or earlier activation layer
x_trunc = tf.slice(x,[0,int(coverlap/2),0],[-1,olength,-1])
x_res = tf.reshape(filter,[-1,olength])
y = ??CONVOLVE??(x_res,filter_res,mode='valid')
# y is final network output
```

I am eager for suggestions on how to create a convolution function in TensorFlow that operates solely on activation - i.e. operates independently on each batch element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I spotted a typo in the code example.  It should be :

Comment: # filter is created as an activation layer
    filter = tf.nn.conv1d(h_conv5, W_fc, stride=1, padding = 'VALID') + b_fc
    filter_res = tf.reshape(filter,[-1,flength])
    # data is created from NN input or earlier activation layer
    x_trunc = tf.slice(x,[0,int(coverlap/2),0],[-1,olength,-1])
    x_res = tf.reshape(x_trunc,[-1,olength])
    y = ??CONVOLVE??(x_res,filter_res,mode='valid')
    # y is final network output

Comment: Also, shape of x_res is (?,2048) and shape of filter_res is (?, 256)